# Flex - Changing the color of a Custom scrollbar using CSS properties

Tags: css, apache-flex, runtime, scrollbar, stylesheet

Currently, I am implementing a scrollbar using a custom embedded image using my CSS stylesheet. This is a very simple, thin scrollbar. I would like to configure this scrollbar using CSS properties at runtime, but so far I have been unable to do so.
I know it can be done because I've seen examples of it in the net, but no code to review. Anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This blog has an example that you can view the source of with a right click:

http://www.axelscript.com/2008/02/20/custom-scroll-bar-using-css/

This one has a few links that redirect to examples with image skins:

http://www.foxarc.com/blog/article/101.htm

You can see a lot of the css stuff for scrollbars and pretty much everything else here:

http://examples.adobe.com/flex3/consulting/styleexplorer/Flex3StyleExplorer.html#

Comment: Thanks for those links invertedSpear.
I am currently using an image skin for the scrollbar, but I want to configure the color of that image skin at runtime using CSS properties. I've tried changing backgroundColor, etc.. on the scrollbar style and that has had no effect. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not familiar with what your doing but I don't think you can change parts of an image with CSS. You can dynamically choose an image source at runtime, with AS or with CSS. Maybe what you need to look into are the actionscript image editors, see if there's a way to take some of that functionlity and apply it to your embedded image.